# Paypal Express Checkout shows only one item

Tags: paypal

I am trying to use Paypal shopping cart in my web page:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Event Registration - Adult">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30.00">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="My Event Registration - Child">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10.00">

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This code is mostly generated using PayPal Payment Button helper on PayPal's website.

It seems PayPal's website generates code only for a single item. As I needed two items, I added another item using input fields `item_name_1` and `amount_1.`

When I click on the submit button, I am properly taken to PayPal's shopping cart. However, I see only one item in the cart. I was expecting to see both, Registration-Adult and Registration-Child, in the shopping cart.

I am wondering what is it that I am missing. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the hidden field "add" can only add one item. You could use "upload" instead. However, in that case PayPal's shopping cart page does not get displayed. For our case, the shopping cart has to be shown so that users can change the number of items. My solution was to actually have two forms instead of one in the same webpage. This works. The only drawback is the user has to click on two buttons instead of one.